# Disabling the zoom/pan/scroll functions for the Webbrowser Control

Tags: windows-phone-7, browser

I have seen many posts about how it's impossible to disable the zoom/pan/scroll functions on the Web-browser control **natively** for Windows Phone 7. So what options do we have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little digging and I found a quick way to do so, so I thought I'd share it here.
It's not a quick few lines of code which is a shame but all of it is up on the web so it should be easy to implement. First you need the Linq ddl and this class here called [LinqToVisualTree](https://gist.github.com/2596707). Then you can use these in a [WebBrowserHelper class](https://gist.github.com/2596720) where you just pass in your web browser when you create the webBrowserHelper and the rest is taken care of. You can even set whether or not you'd like the scrolling to be disabled.

One problem I found with this was that when I double tap on the web page it still zooms in sometimes. Does anyone know how this might be fixed? I'm sure there is a way to do it using the [LinqToVisualTree](https://gist.github.com/2596707) but I can't figure it out.

Comment: This should ONLY be used if you don't have access to the page you are loading. If it's not a third-party page then you can just use user_scalable=no in the meta tags which prevents zoom/pan and works much better then the solution above using LinqToVisualTree.